# Shell command fails from java but works when run manually

Tags: java, bash, shell, gnupg

I'm trying to run some bash commands  that works fine from my console but fails when trying to make the same command call from within Java. The command returns no errors and fails to produce the desired output file. The command is suppose to use a PGP tool (GPG) to decrypt a a file and create another file. This works when run manually but not from within a java app making the same shell call and with no errors.

Just to be sure I even tried chmod 777 on the container folder so I don't think its a permission issue.

**Shell Executor Code (Courtesy of Mkyong.com)**

```
private static String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

**Actual Shell Command**

```
gpg --output /main/decrypted-token.txt --passphrase test /main/token.asc
```

Comment: Where's the script? What command do you send to `executeCommand()`?

Comment: @Biffen At the bottom of the question below "Actual Shell Command"...Forget that I said script. Whether I package it as a .sh file or execute is as a pure string the result is the same.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Biffen Did you actually read the description? The full code is there with "Actual Shell Command" highlighted in Bold?.

Comment: What is the nature of the failure?  Please edit your question to add details.  Does it throw any exceptions?  Print any error messages?  Simply fail to create `/main/decrypted-token.txt`?  Separately, are you able to read `/main/token.asc` from Java or your shell code?  Try `executeCommand("cat /main/token.asc") and see if that works.

Comment: I added more detail...It fails silently. Yes its suppose to create the output file decrypted-token.txt... I will try your suggestion in a moment

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I did, actually. And it's neither *complete* nor *verifiable*, IMO.

Comment: @Biffen Its a paragraph of code that could be reproduced very easily if you have gpg installed on your system. Sorry but I disagree with you completely.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil What are the working directories? What's the path of the script? Which *exact* string do you send to `executeCommand()`?

Comment: All of that info is in the question: The full command entered into executeCommand is "gpg --output /main/decrypted-token.txt --passphrase test /main/token.asc" What else would it be?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil My first two questions are definitely *not* answered by the question.

Answer (score 3):

If the command works fine on the terminal but not when calling from the Java script, the first thing I would try would be to specify Bash on the command being called, see if this works:

```
bash -c "gpg --output /main/decrypted-token.txt --passphrase test /main/token.asc"
```

Or even better:

```
/bin/bash -c "gpg --output /main/decrypted-token.txt --passphrase test /main/token.asc"
```