# Why might a shell command return a 255 status when run from a Codeception test, but work when run manually?

Tags: php, bash, codeception

I am writing a php script and using Codeception to write tests for said script.

When I run the command manually, it works just fine, but for whatever reason, when I run the test with Codeception, it fails to actually run:

`1) DownloadWpCest: Download wordpress
 Test  tests/acceptance/DownloadWpCest.php:downloadFreshFromScratch
 Step  Run shell command "wordpress_update_local"
 Fail  Result code was 255.`

I have also tried running the command using these variations suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128435/884734), and it works just fine manually, but not from the acceptance test:

`bash -c wordpress_update_local
/bin/bash -c wordpress_update_local
/bin/sh -c wordpress_update_local`

I have also tried having Codeception call the `php` binary with the script file specified, and also the above variations, but this has the same result: works manually, but not from Codeception.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that the Composer auto-loader was failing to be included. The suggested include line is:

`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

This relies on the current path to resolve the path to the autoloader, which of course will be different when running a command from within a Codeception test.

I fixed the issue by adding a specific directory:

`require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`